# How to compile threads program?

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, pthreads

I am trying to compile a hello world program using threads. But i keep getting the same error, ive tried it different ways but no luck.

```
gcc hello.c -o hello -lpthread      // command line compilation
./hello.c                            // execution
-bash: ./hello.c: Permission denied // error message
```

Comment: You don't run a .c or .o file; you have to create an executable.  Read the next step in the "Hello world" tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the -o option renames the executable to whatever you write next (in this case 'hello'). You need to execute as ./hello not ./hello.c.